# How to add "Content-type" header in HTTP POST

Tags: ruby, json, header, content-type

I keep getting a

```
400 "Bad Request" (Net::HTTPServerException)
```

error whenever I try to add a content-type header from various methods.

I've seen several different examples and I can't get any to work. My goal is to add a content type of JSON to my request. Without the header, my request doesn't error:

```
def post_data(notice)
    uri = URI('my uri is here')
    http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
    http.use_ssl = true
    req = Net::HTTP::Post.new("#{uri.path}?#{uri.query}")
    text = notice
    req.add_field('Content-Type', 'application/json')
    req.body = "{\"sensu_payload\" = #{payload(text).to_json}}"
    response = http.request(req)
    verify_response(response)
  end
```

I've also tried this method of adding a header:

```
request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(@path, initheader = {'Content-Type' =>'application/json'})
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `uri.path` instead of `@path`:

```
request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.path, initheader = {'Content-Type' =>'application/json'})
```

Comment: There's no difference using `URI` or `URI.parse`. They both return the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `add_field`, I think you should use the hash `[]` form:

```
req['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
```

See the "[Setting Headers](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html#class-Net::HTTP-label-Setting+Headers)" example in the documentation and [`[]=`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTPHeader.html#method-i-5B-5D-3D).

Also, using:

```
"#{uri.path}?#{uri.query}"
```

is never a good idea. String concatenation can't manage the complexities of correctly encoding illegal values in a query, which can break a request. Consider doing something like this instead:

```
require 'uri'

require 'uri'

foo = URI('http://www.example.com') # => #<URI::HTTP http://www.example.com>
foo.query = URI::encode_www_form({'bar' => 'path/to/file', 'baz' => 'this & that'})
foo.to_s # => "http://www.example.com?bar=path%2Fto%2Ffile&baz=this+%26+that"
```

Beyond that, I'd recommend using any of the other HTTP-client gems available. They make it much easier to deal with unexpected situations, like redirects and retries than Net::HTTP. It's more like the building block for features that aren't available other ways.